# Use function to declare array values in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11

first, I'm sorry if I mix up some terms like declare/define, etc. I am currently trying to get familiar with them. My problem is: I have to create a big matrix in my code. I wanted to move this into a separate function at the end of my file to keep things more simple. Is there any easy way to do this? I can not use "vector" because I have to hand the matrix at a later point to a function that does not support "vector" (don't ask, this other function was not written by me).

I currently use this code (since it is working), which declares the matrix in the main function so that it does not go out of scope. I hoped that it is possible to assign the values of the matrix directly in the function, but I couldn't make it work.

```cpp
void make_matrix(float (&matrix_float)[255][4]);

int main()
{
    // ...
    float matrix[255][4]{ 0 };
    make_matrix(matrix);
    // ...
}

void make_matrix(float (&matrix_float)[255][4])
{
    float preparation[255][4]{ { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                               { 0.639999985694885, 0, 0.800000011920929, 1 },
                               { 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                               // ........
                             };

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            {
                matrix_float[i][j] = preparation[i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: What is the problem with the (incomplete) code you show? Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Is it the fact you need an explicit loop that you wish to change?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 255 and 4. It will make the code clearer and changing those numbers easier

Comment: If possible, wrapping the matrix in a class allows to just use assignation (as for `std::array`).

Comment: Instead of a loop you can use a single `memcpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:  Plain arrays are not assignable.

You can initialize arrays at the point of definition. But you cannot later assign a different array to the already existing.

Then, only element wise assignation is possible. As you did in your sub function. You should add at least constexpr to preparation. But it will not really make a difference. A big plus for your passing the 2 dimensional array as reference!

You asked for a more elegant solution. Jarod42 gave already the hint. Wrap the matrix in a POD (Plain Old Structure), a struct. Then C++ will create all kind of special functions, like the assigment operator for you.

Assigning new initializer lists to a POD will work. And instead of matrix, you will write "pod.matrix" . That's it

See example below:

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr size_t Rows = 3;
constexpr size_t Cols = 4;

struct POD
{
    double matrix[Rows][Cols];
};
void makePOD(POD& pod);

int main()
{
    // ...
    POD pod{};
    makePOD(pod);

    std::cout << pod.matrix[1][0];
    // ...
}

void makePOD(POD& pod)
{
    pod = { {   { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.639999985694885, 0.0, 0.800000011920929, 1.0 },
                { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 }
            }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps a little . . .

Comment: `std::array` already serves this purpose, you're reinventing the wheel really